# JavaScript Blob not working on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js, blob

I have some problems with Blob.
I have a website running on Vue 3, and there is one action that is downloading pdf from the backend, but it's not working from mobile browser. It's actually working from the mobile browser, but we have another browser that is opening (just like when you click on facebook url it's opening in their own browser).
So every time when I try to download it from that browser it fails. What am I doing wrong?

```
async function downloadPdfLink(args: IPaymentDownloadPDFArguments): Promise<void> {
    isPDFLoading.value = true;

    return get('/users/' + args.userId + '/payments/' + args.paymentId + '/download-pdf', {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }).then((response) => {
      const blob = new Blob(
          [response.data],
          { type: 'application/pdf' }
        )
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const link = document.createElement('a');
      const name = convertToKebabCase(args.name) + moment(new Date()).format("_YYYY_DD_MM");
      link.href = url;
      link.setAttribute('download', name + '.pdf');
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    })
      .catch((reason) => {
        throw new Error(reason)
      })
      .finally(() => {
        isPDFLoading.value = false;
      })

  }
```

btw I'm not really able to debug it from that browser.

Comment: *mobile* ... ios? android? both? some other mobile device?

Comment: why is `downloadPdfLink` an `async` function if you never `await` anything?

Comment: you can debug it if you try ... you have a catch "reason" that you can display on the page - though, you're probably not hitting that anyway ... no reason for that `catch` block at all, since all you do is rethrow the error

Comment: Both are failing in that case. App is crushing, I cannot see anything :/

Comment: What is "Both"? IOS and Android (presumably Chrome browser)? And now the App is crashing? You didn't mention a crash. A crash isn't the same as "failing to do what I want it to do"